# Query on redudancy of variables in logistic regression

Tags: logistic

I am analyzing data from a study by regressing the variable for "health service utilization", which is coded as 1/0 for use/non-use. The data is for 1440 cases drawn equally from four different sites, and hence I have created four dummy variables, one for each site with 1/0 coding. When I enter these dummy variables as independent variables I am getting the message  "Logistic "Regression Due to redundancies, degrees of freedom have been reduced for one or more variables" and one of the sites is excluded from the equation. 
Reading from this site I checked for collinearity in IVs by using both Pearson's and Spearman's correlation, but did not find any, except for a.6 correlation between sub-groups of age-group, which is coded as a categorical variable.

How can I address this issue? What am I missing? If I am using this approach of four dummies for four sites, I cannot have a equation showing only 3 sites.

Comment: You cannot fit the intercept plus a dummy for each site. Ty removing the intercept.

Comment: Sites should take a value of 1, 2, 3 or 4. When this is coverted to dummy variables, you'll have 3, not 4, dummies. A zero value for all of them indicates the reference site (e.g., number 1). This will let you include all data in a single logistic regression model. Alternatively, you can run an HLM.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that x1, x2, x3, and x4 are used to represent four sites, respectively. In your final regression formula, if you let x1=x2=x3=0, then the result is for x4=1.